# Linear programming mathematical model

Tags: linear-programming, binary-programming

The problem:

There are $N$ cities $(1, 2, \dots, N)$. There are roads connecting $M$ pairs of cities in $N$.

Stores need to be build in way that for each city $X$ store is in city $X$ or in neighboring city.

Find minimal amount of stores that need to be build.

What I need is mathematical model so it can be solved by dedicated solver. I'm pretty sure it will be in binary, I mean if store should be built it needs to be represented as $1$, if not as $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each city $i$, let $N_i$ be the set of neighbors of $i$.
Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether a store is built in city $i$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i y_i$ subject to linear constraints
$$y_i + \sum_{j\in N_i} y_j \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $i$}$$

This is called the minimum [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) problem.